# Solve a circuit with the nodal analysis (3)

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have the following circuit, and I have to find `Vo`:

[image: circuit]

I solved it in this way:

$$
\\
\begin{cases}
\frac{v_1 - 40}{1} + \frac{v_1 - v_0}{2} + 5 = 0
\\
\frac{v_1 - v_0}{2} + 5 = \frac{v_0 - (-20)}{8}  + \frac{v_0}{4} 
\end{cases}
\\
\begin{cases}
2v_1 - 80 + v_1 - v_0 + 10 = 0
\\
4v_1 - 4v_0 + 40 - v_0 -20 - 2v_0 = 0
\end{cases}
\\
\begin{cases}
3v_1 - v_0 = 70
\\
4v_1 - 7v_0 = - 20
\end{cases}
\\
v_0 = 3v_1 - 70
\\
4v_1 - 21v_1 + 490 = -20
\\
17v_1 = 510
\\
v_1 = \frac{510}{17} = 30 V
\\
v_0 = 3v_1 - 70 = 20
\\
\begin{cases}
v_1 = 30 V
\\
v_0 = 20 V
\end{cases}
$$

But the solution is this:

[image: solution]

I think that the error is in the solution, because in the first equation there is:

$$
\frac{40 - v_0}{1}
$$

instead of:

$$
\frac{40 - v_1}{1}
$$

but I'm not sure. Is my solution right or wrong?

Comment: Wrong, I can see without doing any sums that V0 will be positive (+40V from 3ohm source vs -20V from 8ohms source and you have that current source pumping it up too) so you must expect a positive answer.

Comment: Yes, it looks like there's an error in the given solution, but you also have an error in your own setup of the problem, in the second equation.

Comment: Its a badly drawn circuit, I presume that the top of the 4ohm is intended to be connected to the 2 and 8 ohm resistors, not just to the current source.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes thanks, now I have corrected the error.

Comment: If you have edited the question following the answer by Arash Rowsham then you have done him a disservice because now his answer is invalidated. You should either leave alone or clearly explain what you have done to avoid confusion. You have to do something of course, because of this comment.

Comment: @Andyaka, normally I agree 100% with your posts here, but on this one, I can't see where the OP has edited, the answer and the question look consistent to me

Comment: @Andyaka No, for two reason: *(1)* I corrected my solution before I read his comment, *(2)* the error he found it was a transcription error, and the following calculations were not affected by this error. I have corrected *another* error, see [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/216848/revisions) for more information.

Comment: Your updated solution is now correct.

Answer (score 1):

In your solution the second equation should have 8 in the denominator instead of 2:
[image]

Comment: It is a transcription error, the following calculations are not affected by this. However, there was another mistake, which now I have corrected.